# Android : Dependant textboxes triggering each others change events leading to endless loop

Tags: android, android-edittext

Basically I am trying to implement the Google converter kind of thing here. Two EditText controls, and two dropdowns with units for conversion. The user can enter value in any one of the textbox and the conversion takes place (based on the appropriate units selected for each text box). Basically, there is no fixed, to and from text box. Now what happens is (obviously), the change in either of the textbox, triggers the change in the other text box 
i.e. Enter value in Textbox1 --> triggers a conversion and the output is displayed in Textbox2 --> triggering the change event for Textbox2. Now when the calculation for Textbox2 is triggered, I assume no change to take place for the value of Textbox1 and the sequence should stop.... But sadly, for some reason, the sequence does not terminate and the Change events for both textboxes keep getting triggered,until my code crashes due to this endless loop.

Below is what the change event for both EditText controls looks like. (Only the name of the triggering control is different.)

```html
fromValue.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
             public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
             {

             }

             public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                
             }

             public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
             {
                 //we need to trigger the calculation here
                calculate();
             }
         }
        );
```

When I comment out the Change event of any one EditText control, the conversions take place correctly...So the issue is definitely due to the controls triggering each others change events.

I was able to get this done in Obj C and Html using the respective OnChange events for the controls, but Android doesn't seem to agree with this approach. Any insight/help/support on this would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks it's so simple and you are drunk :P
just use a boolean(true value for init) in your activity class and in beginning of onTextChanged just check if the boolean is false just toggle it and exit else set it to false and  change the text.

```
onTextChanged(...) {  
 if(boolean==false)
    return;  
 //reset the flag
 boolean=true; 
 //do your stuff
 return;
 }
```

Comment: Thanx that helped...but probably i am still drunk to not understand why this was needed? Isn't onChange supposed to detect a change and ignore when nothing has changed instead of running in endless loops like a dog chasing his own tail?

Comment: You answer your question yourself, onTextChanged is a dogWatch and it's only duty is to be called when text in the textView is changed and you are chain-chainging the text in textViews so it will be called forever unless you tell it to stop by some means.

Comment: No... i am not chain-changing my textbox values. my scenario is this. User enters a value in textbox1 (say 3), which is to be converted from inch to meters and the result (0.08) displayed in textbox2. This triggers the onchange of textbox2...agree. the onchange for Textbox2 is supposed to calculate conversion of 0.08 from meters to inches. in this case textbox1 already has the value of 3....so no change. And, sadly i realised that your solution does not do the whole job. I have no event to reset the flag. so i am still stuck with my problem.

Comment: I didn't get you, look at my answer I added a comment on it.

Comment: Nah... Am not able to exactly explain my problem in words and a demo is not possible. Guess its time to re-think the approach and probably use some thing that is less likely to get recursive. Thanx for trying.